# MS Access fso.FolderExists against sharepoint is flaky - is there a better way?

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, file-copying, filesystemobject

We have an in house developed ms access "Trial Management System" for an agronomy research company.

The application has evolved over a 15 year period.

We now have three points in the system where we wish to copy files into share point directories instead of to mapped network drives.

Over several weeks I have developed an algorithm that places files into share point directories at the root level of a directory (or site) or several levels down depending on year, client name, contact name and trial number.

This is flexible (driven off a template structure) and reasonably smart.

One of the first lines of code is:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
if fso.FolderExists("some starting sharepoint directory using UNC") then blah, blah
```

This worked fine (returned true) during the entire development process and even on 1/4/2021 when I last tested it.

However, the function returned "false" for all of 5/4/2021 and was working properly again on 6/4/2021.

Our IT department assures me that they have not modified sharepoint or user permissions in that time period.

So I am starting to regard the FileSystemObject with suspicion and thinking that the approach I have used may be naive and flaky.

QUESTION:
Is there a more advanced / solid / reliable way of doing this ?

(I am prepared to write an OCX in C# if that would help)

(It makes much more sense for us to push the files from ms access rather than pull them from sharepoint)

Many thanks in advance
Tony

Comment: More likely, some SharePoint service has been "flaky" that day. Things happen.